# How to iterate through JSON objects in Python and save to a CSV file?

Tags: python, json, csv

I have Python script which retrieves data from an API in JSON format (at least I think its JSON format). I want to loop through each 'object' and write to a CSV file.

Here is the data returned from the api:

```
[
{
    "bids_won": "7",
    "partner_revenue": "$0.01",
    "profit": "$0.00",
    "campaign_id": "test 1", 
    "post_click_conversions": "0", 
    "total_cost": "$0.01",
    "total_media_cost": "$0.01",
    "post_view_conversions": "2", 
    "adjusted_partner_cost": "$0.01", 
    "clicks": "0",
    "day": "August 21, 2011"
},
{
    "bids_won": "30,209", 
    "partner_revenue": "$38.67", 
    "profit": "$8.92", 
    "campaign_id": "test 2", 
    "post_click_conversions": "0", 
    "total_cost": "$29.75", 
    "total_media_cost": "$29.75", 
    "post_view_conversions": "0", 
    "adjusted_partner_cost  ": "$25.26", 
    "clicks": "10", 
    "day": "August 21, 2011"
}
 ]
```

How can I loop through these 'objects' and write them to a CSV file? My current attempt to loop through it results in the script interating through each letter..

Appreciate the help.

ps I'm using python 2.7

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I was given a slightly different URL for the request which returned raw CSV. I dumped the content into a CSV file:

```
f = open('report.csv', 'wb')
f.write(response_content)
f.close
```

Its not an ideal solution because I still cannot loop through the CSV objects (goes through each character) but I'm able to create a resonably well formatted csv file so its ok for now.

Comment: I wish I have enough reputation to downvote this worse question and worst answer! First, json IS a built-in module of python 2.7 so question owner should be able to loop his json.load(...) result. And second, the chosen "answer" does NOT solve the problem (whatever it is) at all! Reading that question and answer is a totally waste of reader's time. (PS: People who agree with this comment please upvote my comment to allow me more reputation to ...)

Comment: This answer doesn't help anyone who comes to the page looking for an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 4):

To convert this to a proper csv file, with keys as a header row, something like this should do it, where "data" is the string containing your json:

```
import json
from csv import DictWriter
dicts = json.loads(data)
the_file = open("sample.csv", "w")
writer = DictWriter(the_file, dicts[0].keys())
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(dicts)
the_file.close()
```

Note that as of Python 2.6, simplejson has been included in the standard library as "json".

Comment: I attempted this but I got the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 45, in <module>
    writer = DictWriter(report_file, dicts[0].keys())
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: Ok, so it seems like your data isn't quite in the same format we were expecting. I suppose you should print it, or a subset of it, to see why it isn't parsing to a dictionary.

Comment: I tried to print out each object by looping through the data but it prints out each character instead of the data for one object...

Comment: That suggests that maybe it is being interpreted as a list containing a single string. That's certainly not too unusual to encounter when working with JSON. Before passing to loads(), data should look something like this: `"[{'a':1, 'b':2,...}...]"`

Comment: Th data looks like this: http://pastebin.com/XMt6e7Ht is it being interpreted as a list containing a single string because of all those backslashes?

Comment: Hmm, when I copy and paste that, and remove the line breaks, then passing it into json.loads() works as expected. How are you getting the representation of the data for pastebin? Just printing it?

Comment: Ok, in order for something to print like that, it means the slashes (and the initial double-quotes) are actually part of the string, rather than escapes. It's equivalent to `data = r'"[{\"a\": 1}]"'`. Are you getting the string exactly like this from the source? If so, you could try `json.loads(data[1:-1].replace("\\", ""))`, which should remove the wrapping double-quotes and strip out the slashes.

Comment: Printing the data seems fine when I pass it into json.loads() - http://pastebin.com/w5ivTQMT - not enclosed within quotes and escaping. However if I try to loop through and display, it prints out each character. If I try to write to write to a CSV file using the code you provided, I get the error I mentioned in my first comment. Seems like they're unicode objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `simplejson` to convert the JSON string to a native Python object. You should then be able to loop through the objects using a standard for loop.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/

```
data = simplejson.loads(JSON_STRING)
```

Comment: Note that in Python 2.6+, `simplejson` included in the standard library, and is simply called `json`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
import json
for i in json.loads(json_string):
    print ','.join(i)
```

See [json module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `simplejson`: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/

With simplejson you can simply do:

```
import simplejson as json

info = """[
{
    "bids_won": "7",
    "partner_revenue": "$0.01",
    "profit": "$0.00",
    "campaign_id": "test 1", 
    "post_click_conversions": "0", 
    "total_cost": "$0.01",
    "total_media_cost": "$0.01",
    "post_view_conversions": "2", 
    "adjusted_partner_cost": "$0.01", 
    "clicks": "0",
    "day": "August 21, 2011"
},
{
    "bids_won": "30,209", 
    "partner_revenue": "$38.67", 
    "profit": "$8.92", 
    "campaign_id": "test 2", 
    "post_click_conversions": "0", 
    "total_cost": "$29.75", 
    "total_media_cost": "$29.75", 
    "post_view_conversions": "0", 
    "adjusted_partner_cost  ": "$25.26", 
    "clicks": "10", 
    "day": "August 21, 2011"
}
 ]"""

data = json.loads(info)
```

And `data` will be a python list that you can iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import csv
temp = json.load(open('filename.json','r'))
output =[]
for each in temp:
     row = {}
     row['field1'] =each['field1']
     row['field2'] = each['field2']
     output.append(row)
file = open( "filename_destination.csv", "w")

fileWriter = csv.writer(file , delimiter=",",quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

Header = ['field1','field2']

fileWriter.writerow(Header)

for x in output:
te = [x['field1'],x['field2']]
fileWriter.writerow(te)
file.close()
```